# Sklearn classifiers do not reset weights after cloning or creating a new instance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I am trying to classify image feature vectors using sklearn's SGD and NN. I want to:

- Shuffle my data
- Split it into train/test
- Train a classifier on the train set and test it on the test set
- Repeat 100 times and calculate average and standard deviation

It seems as though the classifier does not reset its weights however, and the scores increase with every iteration eventually reaching 1. I want a brand new classifier to be trained for every iteration, not continue using one with weights learned from a previous shuffle. Below is the code I am using. I tried to clone model without its weights using the sklearn.base.clone method (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.clone.html) with the neural network, and I tried simply creating a new classifier every iteration with the SGD. Both keep getting higher scores every iteration.

```
NN = MLPClassifier(algorithm='l-bfgs', alpha=1e-05, hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10,), 
            random_state=1, validation_fraction=0.0)

# For every iteration, shuffle data, train model, test model
for j in xrange(100):   
    # Shuffle data
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = shuffle_data(biz_features, biz_labels)

    # Classify using NN
    NN_clone = clone(NN, safe = True)
    y_pred_NN = NN_clone.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)

    # Classify using SGD
    SGD = OneVsRestClassifier(
        SGDClassifier(
            random_state=0,
            loss = 'hinge',
            alpha = 0.00001,
            penalty = 'elasticnet')).fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred_SGD = SGD.predict(X_test)

    # Evaluate ..
```

Comment: Why don't you just re-assign inside the loop `NN = MLPClassifier(algorithm='l-bfgs', alpha=1e-05, hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10,), 
            random_state=1, validation_fraction=0.0)`?

Comment: That is what I do with the SGD, below, I try to show the two different methods that I used to try to fix this problem. Both do not work.

Comment: Can you add the code for `shuffle_data`? As it seems tis behaviour **should** be impossible due to the `warm_start` parameter in both `MLPClassifier` and in `SGDClassifier`